# Error: 'argument' does not name a type, supposed problems with .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, arduino, include, mqtt

I read about this issue (seems quite common) for hours without finding any applicable solution to my situation. I understand that there might be a problem related to the included files and libraries, but I'm not actually able to find what's wrong.

It's an Arduino script that uses the MQTT client library. It works beautifully with the old PubSubClient.h lib.

Now I wanted to update the lib with a recent one. The function definitions are changed so I made the changes in the sketch and switched the lib in the Arduino/library directory, then restarted the Arduino IDE. I get lot of "error: 'argument' does not name a type" and I really don't know what to fix.

Here you can find the .h and .cpp files organization to understand what's happening.

//device.ino file

```
#include "device.h"
```

//device.h file

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <jsmn.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <pgmspace.h>
#include "mqtt.h"

#endif
```

mqtt.h file

```
#ifndef MQTT_H
#define MQTT_H

#include "device.h"

#endif
```

mqtt.cpp file

```
#include "mqtt.h"

WiFiClient wifi_client;
PubSubClient mqtt_client(wifi_client);
mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, MQTT_BROKER_PORT);
mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);
```

Finally the errors the compiler throws out:
    mqtt.cpp:19: error: 
         'mqtt_client' does not name a type

```
     mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, MQTT_BROKER_PORT);

     ^

    mqtt.cpp:20: error: 'mqtt_client' does not name a type

     mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);

     ^

    sketch\mqtt.cpp: In function 'void mqtt_publish_mex(String, String, bool)':

    mqtt.cpp:27: error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(String&, String&, bool&)'

             if (mqtt_client.publish(topic, jmex, retained)) {

                                                          ^

    sketch\mqtt.cpp:27:54: note: candidates are:

    In file included from sketch\Walvola.h:25:0,

                     from sketch\mqtt.h:4,

                     from sketch\mqtt.cpp:1:

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:130:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:130:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:131:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*, boolean)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload, boolean retained);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:131:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:132:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:132:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:133:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int, boolean)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength, boolean retained);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:133:12: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided

    sketch\mqtt.cpp: In function 'void mqtt_log(String)':

    mqtt.cpp:347: error: no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(const String&, String&)'

             mqtt_client.publish(mqtt_controllers_topic_debug, json_string);

                                                                          ^

    sketch\mqtt.cpp:347:70: note: candidates are:

    In file included from sketch\Walvola.h:25:0,

                     from sketch\mqtt.h:4,

                     from sketch\mqtt.cpp:1:

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:130:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:130:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const String' to 'const char*'

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:131:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const char*, boolean)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const char* payload, boolean retained);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:131:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:132:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:132:12: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:133:12: note: boolean PubSubClient::publish(const char*, const uint8_t*, unsigned int, boolean)

        boolean publish(const char* topic, const uint8_t * payload, unsigned int plength, boolean retained);

                ^

    C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\pubsubclient\src/PubSubClient.h:133:12: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided

    In file included from sketch\mqtt.h:4:0,

                     from sketch\mqtt.cpp:1:

    sketch\mqtt.cpp: In function 'void mqtt_callback(char*, byte*, unsigned int)':

    mqtt.cpp:375: error: request for member 'payload_string' in 'payload', which is of non-class type 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}'

             log(payload.payload_string());

                         ^

    sketch\Walvola.h:89:67: note: in definition of macro 'log'

     #define log(mex) if (DEBUG) {Serial.println(walvola_time + "::" + mex);Serial.flush(); if(MQTT_DEBUG) {mqtt_log(walvola_time + "::" + mex);}}

                                                                       ^

    mqtt.cpp:375: error: request for member 'payload_string' in 'payload', which is of non-class type 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}'

             log(payload.payload_string());

                         ^

    sketch\Walvola.h:89:135: note: in definition of macro 'log'

     #define log(mex) if (DEBUG) {Serial.println(walvola_time + "::" + mex);Serial.flush(); if(MQTT_DEBUG) {mqtt_log(walvola_time + "::" + mex);}}

                                                                                                                                           ^

    mqtt.cpp:379: error: request for member 'payload_string' in 'payload', which is of non-class type 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}'

             if (mqtt2JSONkvs(payload.payload_string())) {

                                      ^

    mqtt.cpp:404: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

     {

     ^

    mqtt.cpp:512: error: expected '}' at end of input

     }

     ^

    Più di una libreria trovata per "WiFiClient.h"
    Usata: C:\Users\Fabrizio & Dario\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi
    Non usata: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
    Non usata: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
    Non usata: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
    Non usata: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
    exit status 1
    'mqtt_client' does not name a type
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when writing

```
WiFiClient wifi_client;
PubSubClient mqtt_client(wifi_client);
mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, MQTT_BROKER_PORT);
mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);
```

the first two lines are quite ok => you are declaring global variables named `wifi_client` and `mqtt_client`

The problem comes with the calls

```
mqtt_client.setServer(mqtt_server, MQTT_BROKER_PORT);
mqtt_client.setCallback(mqtt_callback);
```

You can declare variables at global scope, but you cannot call functions outside a function (unless is for a global variable initialization), this is why you get this error. The example you point is different as the variables are in a function, thus calling methodes on them just after is legal: you are in a function context.

So you need to move your calls in the main() function, for example, so that the code gets valid.

That said, putting global variables in the header could make you more trouble is you include you file from different cpp files, the compiler will complain about multiple definitions, but that is not (yet) the question here.

Comment: Thanks, I used the funciton with parameters instead of the member function like this:

    PubSubClient mqtt_client(mqtt_server, MQTT_BROKER_PORT, 
    mqtt_callback, wifi_client);


But I think something still is wrong, can't use the same for the call:

    mqtt_client.publish(topic, jmex, retained)


I checked also the exemple and in that are used the calls  [link] (https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/examples/mqtt_esp8266/mqtt_esp8266.ino) row 112, 130..

Comment: Not really but it was a time ago the last time I used. I was just doing in the same way as the example , declaring the pubsubclient object and than calling the public functions. Can you clear more where you would move that code (as your previous answer)? Maybe its simple for you but I'm going crazy, thank you!

Comment: see my modifications

Comment: ok, thank you! It seems it's leading me to a solution, now I have to change the parameters type of my functions that give data to mqtt_client.publish(const char* topic, const char* payload), before this function was publish(const String topic, String payload). How i can switch from Strings to char* without making mistakes?